# or tools routing visit order

Tags: routes, traveling-salesman, or-tools

Some nodes are more important than others, so we need to visit them first. Is there a method to force the vehicles to do this
I tried the following but it does not work

```
   routing.ApplyLocksToAllVehicles([[0,x] for x in [1,2,3,4,5,6]], True)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add a soft penalty on the cumul vars of these nodes on the time or rank of the visit. See https://discord.com/channels/693088862481678374/702786263098458132/750395687644168254 for some inspiration, although it does not solve exactly the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I see nothing when I click on the link

Comment: Another example of using soft constraints: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56788628/518804 (although again, it does not directly address your specific question)